# Android studio. ListView "перекрывает" объекты стоящие ниже

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Нужно сделать прокручивающийся фрагмент. Надо добавить `ListView`, а после него `Checkout` кнопку.

Как выглядит xml:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="uk.ac.ox.oaxacaapp.main"
    android:layout_marginTop="64.2dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Checkout Order"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_checkout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Checkout" />


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: укажите нужный `marginBottom` для `ListView`, чтобы он не перекрывал кнопку

Comment: @mit у меня динамический ListView... поэтому не могу сказать сколько нужно отступа вниз...

Comment: какая разница, как вы формируете лист, не важно динамический он или нет. На его расположение в лэйауте это никак не влияет, содержимое будет прокручиваться в соответствующем контейнере. Я вам margin предлагаю добавить, а не pading расчитывать.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="64.2dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checkout Order"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_checkout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Checkout" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: слишком сложно и лишняя вложенность контейнеров

Comment: @mit - это не подходит

Comment: @pavlofff согласен, но ответ дан в рамках конкретной задачи, а ваш комментарий лучше перенести в сам вопрос